# Magento crashes after theme installation

Tags: magento-1.9

After having installed a theme in Magento and played around a little bit on my next restart I tried to reach the site and I'm getting this error

```
Notice: Undefined index: catalog.topnav  in /var/www/html/magento1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php on line 460

  #0 /var/www/html/magento1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(460): mageCoreErrorHandler(8, 'Undefined index...', '/var/www/html/m...', 460, Array)

  #1 /var/www/html/magento1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(472): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('page/html_topme...', 'catalog.topnav')
 #2 /var/www/html/magento1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(239): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->addBlock('page/html_topme...', 'catalog.topnav')
 #3 /var/www/html/magento1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(205): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#4 /var/www/html/magento1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(206): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#5 /var/www/html/magento1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(206): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
 #6 /var/www/html/magento1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(206): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
   #7 /var/www/html/magento1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(344): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()
 #8 /var/www/html/magento1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(113): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
#9 /var/www/html/magento1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(52): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->_renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'home')
#10 /var/www/html/magento1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/controllers/IndexController.php(45): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'home')
 #11 /var/www/html/magento1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Cms_IndexController->indexAction()
 #12 /var/www/html/magento1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#13 /var/www/html/magento1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
 #14 /var/www/html/magento1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#15 /var/www/html/magento1.9/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#16 /var/www/html/magento1.9/index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
#17 {main}
```

I assume it's the theme's fault because I came across the same post somewhere on the internet but I'm not sure on how to remove the theme. Any fix on this or do I have to remove the theme ?

Thank you..!!

Comment: Just the delete the theme files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the error tels that your theme can't find `catalog.topnav` block in layout,

```
<block type="page/html_topmenu" name="catalog.topnav" template="page/html/topmenu.phtml"/>
```

Check this in your layout theme `app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/layout/page.xml` or try to add the code bellow in `local.xml` :

```
<block type="page/html_header" name="header" as="header">
    <block type="page/template_links" name="top.links" as="topLinks"/>
    <block type="page/switch" name="store_language" as="store_language" template="page/switch/languages.phtml"/>
    <block type="core/text_list" name="top.menu" as="topMenu" translate="label">
        <label>Navigation Bar</label>
        <block type="page/html_topmenu" name="catalog.topnav" template="page/html/topmenu.phtml"/>
    </block>
    <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="top.container" as="topContainer" translate="label">
        <label>Page Header</label>
        <action method="setElementClass"><value>top-container</value></action>
    </block>
    <block type="page/html_welcome" name="welcome" as="welcome"/>
</block>
```

Check also `app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/page/html/topmenu.phtml`

If you don't want to use this new theme, you have to go to:**Admin->system->configuration->design**

`Package:` You put the package name of the theme that it worked before, not the new one.

`Themes:` You put the theme name of the theme that it worked before in : template, skin, layout, default.

With this config, Magento will not load the new theme files, **but** if you have overwritten the other files of the old theme with the new one, this is another problem.

Good luck.

Comment: hhmmm.... didn't work... are you sure  local.xml Ihave to add it in  ?

Comment: look my update please

Comment: I'm not sure what happened...  :-(   but in app/design/frontend  there in base, default and rwd.  My theme is in app/design/frontend/default/theme_name. Are my files overwritten ?

Comment: No, if your theme name is in `app/design/frontend/default/theme name/...` and not in `app/design/frontend/default/default/...`it's good

Answer (score 0):

While the most obvious thing to do was to delete all the theme files, I figured out that there was a megamenu module that came with the theme. So in the **Configuration->Advanced** section I just disabled the module and the page loads properly without the mega menu of course. Seems like a lot of people had the same problem with the specific theme.